# Dropdown Select Not Displaying Form

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a dropdown list where when the value is selected it would display another form, for some reason it doesn't seem to work...

**HTML:**

```
<select id='purpose'>
        <option value="0">Nameglow</option>
        <option value="1">Namecolor</option>
        <option value="2">Bubbleglow</option>
        <option value="3">Bubblecolor</option>
    </select>

    <form id="nameglow">
            <input class="jscolor" type="text" name="nameglow" maxlength="6" id="color">
            <input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeNameglow()">
    </form>

    <form id="namecolor">
        <input class="jscolor" type="text" name="namecolor" maxlength="6" id="color">
        <input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeNamecolor()">
    </form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    switch (this.value) {
            case 0:
                $("#namecolor").hide();
                $("#bubbleglow").hide();
                $("#bubblecolor").hide();
                $("#nameglow").show();
            break;
            case 1:
                $("#nameglow").hide();
                $("#bubbleglow").hide();
                $("#bubblecolor").hide();
                $("#namecolor").show();
            break;
            case 2:
                $("#namecolor").hide();
                $("#nameglow").hide();
                $("#bubblecolor").hide();
                $("#bubbleglow").show();
            break;
            case 3:
                $("#namecolor").hide();
                $("#nameglow").hide();
                $("#bubbleglow").hide();
                $("#bubblecolor").show();
            break;
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
 #nameglow {
        display:none;
    }

    #namecolor { 
        display:none;
    }

    #bubbleglow { 
        display:none;
    }

    #bubblecolor { 
        display:none;
    }
```

I tried using javascript but I'm facing the same issue..I prefer using jquery, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I haven't added the bubble glow and bubble color form yet.

Comment: Shouldn't it be '$(this).val()' in the switch instead of 'this.value'? if using jQuery

Comment: tried changing that but doesn't fix the issue... https://jsfiddle.net/fycjrouo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
this.value
```

Into:

```
$(this).prop('selectedIndex');
```

Or:

```
parseInt($(this).val());
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1csdnmq/)

It doesn't display any form initially even though Nameglow is selected because you don't check for the selected value until the select option is changed.

**UPDATE:**

I updated my answer to reflect that parseInt() is required if you want to use $(this).val() like Ness Rosales pointed out. I did not catch that at first.

Comment: `$(this).prop('selectedIndex');` worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Otherwise @Ness Rosales was right too, because the "value" is char/string and your switch was looking for integer values. That's why 'selectedIndex' worked because it's a number. Converting the .val() works too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the reference to jQuery, here is a site where you can find a CDN for it [jQuery CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)

Now the issue is in the switch, the correct syntax is

```
switch($(this).val())
```

The other problem is that you are checking for integer values and the the value in the dropdown is a char/string, in order to get it to work you need to convert it to int like this

```
switch(parseInt($(this).val()))
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr3anj3p/1/)